# Correcting a column in Rails Postgresql database (timezone issue)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, heroku, utc

When I built my web app it was, unknowingly to me, set to use UTC by default. One of my model's attributes is a DateTime called event_date which is manually set by the user. The users thought they we're selecting CST while behind the scenes everything was still in UTC.

Now I am pulling events from Facebook Graph API, and they display the "wrong" time (what I recently found out is *actually* the correct UTC time). When I changed my application.rb file to include

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

It solves the issue of the Facebook times being wrong. However, all of my previous database entries are now incorrect due to their event_date's being entered as incorrect UTC times.

What is the best way to go about resolving this? I assume the best method would be to convert or offset the entire event_date column of my database to the correct UTC time, but I am unsure how to go about doing this.

The app is built with Ruby on Rails, I'm using Postgresql, and I am deploying through Heroku.

Comment: Have you tried to save time_zone user sets to database and later on convert it to correct one? You can then set time with in_time_zone function. Every date in rails is saved in UTC format.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution for the future if I am understanding you correctly, but what about adjusting my current database, which lacks a time_zone field, to the correct one? All of my entries need 6 hrs added to their event_date since right now we are only dealing with CST.

Comment: well, you can update all users to that time zone, or if you are certain that you have only one timezone that you can use in_time_zone function with hardcoded timezone.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I'm following. My model is for events, with images, titles, etc. and an event_date. The event_date's are all stored in UTC in my Postrgres database, and are all off their actual times by 6 hours. I would like to update my entire database to have their event_date field be shifted 6 hours. Following that, I will change the Rails default time_zone to CST and the problem should be gone moving forward. If and when we have users in new timezones, I will account for that. Does this process make sense? And if so how do I go about changing all my event's date_event fields at once?

Comment: Problem is that rails always saves UTC to database, I tried to change that several times but unsuccessfully... you can change date showed to user by changing it in controller/helper, but I think it is not possible... I think that best practice is to have consistent time in database, therefore UTC, and convert later on in timezone you need.

Comment: I get that much. That is why I am saying that if I add 6 hours to my already existing event_dates they will be the correct time in UTC. Then I will make sure to call them with the correct timezone conversion in the view from now on.

What I'm asking at this point is how to add 6 hours to every entry in my Heroku App's PSQL Database. Do I need to pull the database to my local comp, update, and repush it live? And how do I go about adding 6 hours to each DateTime field all at once?

Comment: Can you try something like : User.all.each{|u|  u.event_date = u.event_date + 6.hours; u.save}; nil ?